# What's the rationale behind the [B]Quarter[Begin|End] offset not counting quarters relative to Jan?

Tags: pandas

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.QuarterBegin.html?highlight=quarterbegin#) provide examples of this as well, but they don't explain why the behaviour is as it is.

Anytime I've heard of anything to do with a quarter, it's always been Q1, Q2, Q3 or Q4 which starts Jan, April, July, Oct, respectively.  Why is that not the default, and why is `3` the default `startingMonth`?

```py
from pandas import Timestamp
from pandas.tseries.offsets import QuarterBegin, QuarterEnd
timestamp = Timestamp('2023-01-31 21:00:00+00:00')
print(timestamp + QuarterBegin())
print(timestamp + QuarterBegin(startingMonth=1))
print(timestamp + QuarterBegin(startingMonth=2))
print(timestamp + QuarterBegin(startingMonth=3))
print(timestamp + QuarterEnd())
print(timestamp + QuarterEnd(startingMonth=1))
print(timestamp + QuarterEnd(startingMonth=2))
print(timestamp + QuarterEnd(startingMonth=3))

>>>
2023-03-01 21:00:00+00:00
2023-04-01 21:00:00+00:00
2023-02-01 21:00:00+00:00
2023-03-01 21:00:00+00:00
2023-03-31 21:00:00+00:00
2023-04-30 21:00:00+00:00
2023-02-28 21:00:00+00:00
2023-03-31 21:00:00+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to ask Wes McKinney (https://stackoverflow.com/users/776560/wes-mckinney), as it's been that way since he did the initial commit of Pandas in 2009, and it's very hard to change a default that's been around this long:

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/c6b236db73ff81007909be6406f0e484edc4a9eb

Browse to datetools.py, line 320:[image: self.startingMonth = kwds.get('startingMonth',3)]